# how to hide a div in php using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a div which needs to be hide with php script. Here is the code that I have written so far...but I am not getting the exact result...

```
<?php
$s = "2";
if($s == "1")
{
echo "empty fr";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('#ts').style.display = 'none';</script>
<?php
}
?>
<div id="ts"><label for="terry">Text<input type="checkbox" name="Terry" id="terry" value="1" /></label></div>
```

Comment: try document.getElementById('ts'), the id doesn't have the "#"

Comment: You have your script before the element, you need to use an onload callback as the dom is not ready when your script is ran and it cannot find the element, along with the dont use the '#' in getElementById

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
document.getElementById('#ts').style.display = 'none';
```

by

```
document.getElementById('ts').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: I have done it but still its displaying as per logic of my code it should not display the checkbox

Comment: This answer is missing half of the problem. The hiding attempt is happening before the element is loaded.

Comment: True .. Pietu's answer is complete.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here.

Firstly, the one suggested by most answerers.

```
document.getElementById('#ts').style.display = 'none';
```

You won't need the `#` here. Remove it.

```
document.getElementById('ts').style.display = 'none';
```

But, there is another thing. You are calling this code *before* the element to hide is loaded, so it won't work. You'll have to either

- move the `<script>` after the element to hide

  ```
  <div id="ts"><label for="terry">Text<input type="checkbox" name="Terry" id="terry" value="1" /></label></div>
  <?php
  $s = "2";
  if($s == "1")
  {
  echo "empty fr";
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('#ts').style.display = 'none';</script>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  ```

  If the code you posted is all of the code in that part, this shouldn't cause any side effects as you are not printing any visible content in that part of the PHP.
- use the `onload` event.

  ```
  <?php
  $s = "2";
  if($s == "1")
  {
  echo "empty fr";
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener("load", function(){
      document.getElementById('ts').style.display = 'none';
  });
  </script>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  <div id="ts"><label for="terry">Text<input type="checkbox" name="Terry" id="terry" value="1" /></label></div>
  ```

  This calls the function when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `#` in document.getElementById()

just use it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('ts').style.display = 'none';</script>
```

Comment: This answer is missing half of the problem. The hiding attempt is happening before the element is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use the `#` character when using the pure JavaScript `getElementById` method call.

So, just change your call to this:

```
document.getElementById('ts').style.display = 'none';
```

The hash character is only needed for jQuery, as it uses the Sizzle engine for selectors.

You can learn more about the method call [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).

Comment: This answer is missing half of the problem. The hiding attempt is happening before the element is loaded.